# Recode NA with values from similar ID with data.table

Tags: r, data.table, recode

I'm in a learning process to use `data.table` and trying to recode NA to the non-missing values by `b`.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = rep(1:3, 2),
                 b = c(rep(1,3), rep(2, 3)),
                 c = c(NA, 4, NA, 6, NA, NA))

> dt
   a b  c
1: 1 1 NA
2: 2 1  4
3: 3 1 NA
4: 1 2  6
5: 2 2 NA
6: 3 2 NA
```

I would like to get this:

```
> dt
   a b  c
1: 1 1  4
2: 2 1  4
3: 3 1  4
4: 1 2  6
5: 2 2  6
6: 3 2  6
```

I tried these, but none gives the desired result.

```
dt[, c := ifelse(is.na(c), !is.na(c), c), by = b]
dt[is.na(c), c := dt[!is.na(c), .(c)], by = b]
```

Appreciate to get some helps and a little bit explanation on how should I consider/think when trying to solve the problem with `data.table` approach.

Comment: Will you have the case where there is more than one `c` value for each `b` group?

Comment: Not the case I currently have in hand, but I suppose could implement conditioning for the value one would have once the problem I posted is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a simple case where there is just one `c` for each level of `b`:

```
dt[, c := c[!is.na(c)][1], by = b]
dt
```

Comment: Should be `!is.na`. Thanks for another suggestion.

Comment: @yuskam Thanks for pointing out. Using `[1]` should be faster than `unique()` if the vector is large.

Comment: I realised also it's easier to select desired value if `c` has more than 1. So I selected ur answer since it solves more than one issues.